# What is the most convenient way to load/save property files in Android?

Tags: java, android

I was thinking about using the functionality built in the `Properties` API then I found the `AssetManager`. Is there some very simplistic way for loading/saving property files in Android? One that doesn't involve messing with Input/Output streams.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think Shared Preferences is good for small data.
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref

Comment: Great, that's what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen SharedPreferences? http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref